# Rounding floating number using AWK

Tags: awk, printf

I have a file b.xyz as,

```
-19.794325 -23.350704 -9.552335
-20.313872 -23.948248 -8.924463
-18.810708 -23.571757 -9.494047
-20.048543 -23.660052 -10.478968
```

I want to limit each of the entries to three decimal digits.

I tried this one

```
awk '{ $1=sprintf("%.3f",$1)} {$2=sprintf("%.3f",$2)} {$3=sprintf("%.3f",$3)} {print $1, $2, $3}' b.xyz
```

it works for three columns, but how to expand it to apply for n/all columns?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make sense, 4lines of input, 6 lines of output? -19.794345 should round to -19.794, which it DOES in my test, but NOT in your sample output. (I do confirm that field 3 of line 1 doesn't get rounded, which I don't understand.). Please update your question, rather than answering in comments. Good luck.

Comment: it prints each lines twice!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you will always have three fields, then you can use:

```
$ awk '{printf "%.3f %.3f %.3f\n", $1, $2, $3}' file
-19.794 -23.351 -9.552
-20.314 -23.948 -8.924
-18.811 -23.572 -9.494
-20.049 -23.660 -10.479
```

For an undefined number of lines, you can do:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%.3f%s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":" ")}' file
-19.794 -23.351 -9.552
-20.314 -23.948 -8.924
-18.811 -23.572 -9.494
-20.049 -23.660 -10.479
```

It will loop through all the fields and print them. `(i==NF?"\n":" ")` prints a new line when the last item is reached.

Or even ([thanks Jotne!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306770/awk-rounding-floating-number/22307026?noredirect=1#comment33896311_22307026)):

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%.3f %s", $i, (i==NF?RS:FS)}' file
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
-19.794325 -23.350704 -9.552335 2.13423 23 23223.23 23.23442
-20.313872 -23.948248 -8.924463
-18.810708 -23.571757 -9.494047
-20.048543 -23.660052 -10.478968

$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%.3f %s", $i, (i==NF?"\n":" ")}' a
-19.794 -23.351 -9.552  2.134  23.000  23223.230  23.234 
-20.314 -23.948 -8.924 
-18.811 -23.572 -9.494 
-20.049 -23.660 -10.479 

$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%.3f %s", $i, (i==NF?RS:FS)}' a
-19.794  -23.351  -9.552  2.134  23.000  23223.230  23.234 
-20.314  -23.948  -8.924 
-18.811  -23.572  -9.494 
-20.049  -23.660  -10.479
```

Comment: I would have change `(i==NF?"\n":" ")` to `(i==NF?RS:FS)` and may have golfing some to: `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%.3f"(i==NF?RS:FS),$i}'`

Comment: Very good one, @Jotne, thanks! Just updated to reflect that other possibility (note in your comment you missed the `%s` part)

Comment: No, I do not miss the `%s`, If you look, I have moved the `(i==NF?RS:FS)` to the other side of `,` so it just replaces an extra data input, the golfing part.

Comment: Just a little add-on question to this excellent answer: how do you add in the formatting for 'thousands'? So in case of your example '23223.230' would become '23,223.230'. I now have this `awk '{printf ("%'\''.2f\n", $0)}' | awk '{printf ("%'\''d\n", $0)}'`, but that doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan use `'` as described in [`printf()` modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html). For example if I type `LC_NUMERIC=en_US awk '{printf ("%'\''f\n", $0)}' <<< 23223.230` I get `23,223.23000`.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the answer @fedorqui!